# What does Automatic mean in the context of VerifySolutions for NSolve?

Tags: equation-solving, options

A quick check for the options of `NSolve` yields:

```
 Options[NSolve]
```

> ```
>  {Method -> Automatic, RandomSeed -> 0, 
>   VerifySolutions -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> Automatic}
> ```

Does anyone know what `VerifySolutions -> Automatic` means in this case? `Automatic` to me usually means 'make reasonable guess', as in `PlotRange -> Automatic`, but I don't know what Mathematica thinks is reasonable, and I don't know how to dig any deeper into the underlying code in Mathematica.

I should add that I know how to verify solutions by hand by feeding them back into the original equations. I also know that I can force the option by setting `VerifySolutions -> True`. I have found that this typically takes a bit longer for the equations I am solving which makes me think `Automatic` means `False` in my case. But in either case, I am none-the-less still curious about my original question.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation for `VerifySolutions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerifySolutions.html)?

Comment: @ J.M. I did... it says automatic means it  'automatically determine whether to verify'...which seems a bit tautological unless I am missing something...

Comment: The [docs for `NSolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html#55614444) also give a short demo.

Comment: @ J.M. I saw that too. It says 'NSolve verifies solutions obtained using non-equivalent transformations...' I wasn't sure if I should interpret that as 'NSolve will verify under certain unstated conditions ' or 'NSolve will always verify under any conditions '. I suppose I could restate my question as, 'if NSolve always verifies the solutions, why isn't VerifySolutions->True the default?

Comment: Typical cases that get the attention of the verifier include presence of denominators or radicals in the original equations.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [`VerifySolutions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerifySolutions):

> [`VerifySolutions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerifySolutions) controls whether the solutions obtained using non-equivalent transformations or numerical methods should be verified.

One example of a non-equivalent transformation is when inverse functions are being used. Here is an example. First the default case with [`VerifySolutions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerifySolutions)->[`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic):

```
TracePrint[
    NSolve[Sin[x] == .5, x],
    Sin[_Real],
    TraceInternal->True
]
```

> Sin[0.52359877559830]
>
> NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> {{x -> 0.523599}}

Now, repeat with [`VerifySolutions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerifySolutions)->[`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False):

```
TracePrint[
    NSolve[Sin[x] == .5, x, VerifySolutions->False],
    Sin[_Real],
    TraceInternal->True
]
```

> NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> {{x -> 0.523599}}

Notice that this time the solution isn't verified (i.e., this time `Sin[0.52359877559830]` is not evaluated to check whether it's zero).